# UIView.animate - using .autoreverse with other options

Tags: swift, uiview, uiviewanimationtransition

When using `UIView.animate` with `.autoReverse`, does it keep other options during the auto reverse? If I have a `.curveEaseOut`, is that option kept for the reverse, or will it just use the default `.curveLinear` option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes**, the `UIView` animation block will respect other options besides `.autoreverse`. You can check this for yourself by providing an array containing `.autoreverse` and for e.g. `.curveEaseOut` as the parameter for `options`.